# Como funciona o Length fora e dentro do For no Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loop, for

eu tenho uma dúvida constante sobre o `Length` e o laço `for` para medir um array ou uma string.

**Dúvida 1:**

Quando usamos esse código:

```js
const numero ="teste";
const medir = numero.length;
console.log(medir)
```

Ele retorna o valor 5. Mas se usamos como array:

```js
const numero = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
const medir = numero.length;
console.log(medir)
```

Ele retorna 3. Por que ?

**Dúvida 2:**

Como que funciona dentro do For? Tenho o código:

```js
   const separador = " - ";

function filtro(funcao, numeros2) {

let stringNova = '';

for (let i = 0; i < numeros2.length; i++) {

    stringNova += numeros2[i] + (funcao)
}
return stringNova
}

console.log(filtro(separador, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

```
    for (let i = 0; i < numero.length; i++)
```

Como exatamente funciona este trecho de código? Pessoas me explicam mas me explicam de forma técnica e eu sou novato e não fica tão claro para mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dúvida #1:**

```
const numero ="teste";
const medir = numero.length;
console.log(medir)
```

Sua variável numero é do tipo texto (`string`) a propriedade `length` retorna a quantidade de caracteres.

```
const numero = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
const medir = numero.length;
console.log(medir)
```

Sua variável é um vetor (`array`) a propriedade `length` retorna a quantidade de elementos.

**Dúvida #2**

Dentro do for funciona igual das duas maneiras que citei acima, o valor do `length` será baseado no tipo da variável.

O primeiro código, retorna a quantidade de elementos já que você está passando um array como parâmetro.

```js
const separador = " - ";

function filtro(funcao, numeros2) {

  let stringNova = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < numeros2.length; i++) {
    stringNova += numeros2[i] + (funcao)
  }
  return stringNova
}

console.log(filtro(separador, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

E esse último trecho de código baseado que a variável `numero` é a mesma do código do começo da sua pergunta, retorna a quantidade de letras, então vai rodar o looping 5 vezes.

```
for (let i = 0; i < numero.length; i++)
```

Comment: Então este código signifca que:

Enquanto `i(0)` for menor que  `numero.length(5 )`; vai incrementar até `i` for igual a `numero` ?

Comment: Isso, enquanto `i` for menor.

Answer (score 2):

O laço **for** geralmente é usado para percorrer os elementos de uma array. Imagine uma rua com casas, começando da *Casa 1*, *Casa 2*, *Casa 3* e assim por diante. Da mesma forma é uma array, um objeto que contém elementos organizados tal como uma rua com casas, com a diferença de que na array o endereço começa com *Casa 0*, *Casa 1* etc., ou seja, numa array, o primeiro endereço é sempre 0 (chamado de *índice* ou *index*).

Logo, uma array com 3 elementos, por exemplo, o índice máximo que ela pode ter é 2, porque começa do 0, 1, 2 (3 itens).

```
var array = ['Maria','Joao','Jose']; // Total de 3 itens
                ↑       ↑      ↑
                0       1      2     // índices
```

Por isso no **for** a variável começa com 0 e vai até o total de itens - 1 (3 - 1 = 2), que é o índice máximo na array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numeros2.length; i++) {
                          ↑
                enquanto "i" for menor que
              a quantidade de itens na array
```

Uma vez que `i` for igual à quantidade de itens na array, a condição no **for** (`numeros2.length`) não será mais satisfeita e o laço é *encerrado*.